# Add column to pandas dataframe based on previous values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with an observation number, and id, and a number

```
Obs#   Id    Value
--------------------
1        1   5.643
2        1   7.345
3        2   0.567
4        2   1.456
```

I want to calculate a new column that is the mean of the previous values of a specific id

I am trying to use something like this but it only acquires the previous value:

```
df.groupby('Id')['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1) ...
```

My question is how do I acquire the range of previous values filtered by the Id so I can calculate the mean ?

So the new column based on this example should be

```
5.643
6.494
0.567
1.0115
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you want [**`expanding`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html), then **`mean`**

```
df.groupby('Id').Value.expanding().mean()

Id
1.0  1    5.6430
     2    6.4940
2.0  3    0.5670
     4    1.0115
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Never used `expanding`, nice +1

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `expanding()`.

Comment: To merge this groupby series back into the original df I used `series = series.sortlevel(level=1)` and then `df['Mean'] = series.values`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Obs':[1,2,3,4],'Id':[1,1,2,2],'Value':[5.643,7.345, 0.567,1.456]})

df.groupby('Id')['Value'].apply(lambda x:  x.cumsum()/np.arange(1, len(x)+1))
```

It gives output as :

```
5.643
6.494
0.567
1.0115
```